# Karate UI Automation support

Tags: user-interface, selenium-webdriver, automation, karate

wanted to explore on Karate UI Automation (selenium) support.
found out that a jar is available for it click [https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:karate-core]

any blogs which can help to start with it like:
browser configuration
Initiating the webdriver/karate driver?

karate UI automation documentation provided few code snippets but no clue on how to start, please guide.

Added karate jar available (https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:karate-core) but when i try driver.location("http://sampledotcom") writing this code on feature file, the gherkin is not identifying these lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core

And also see this example: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-sikulix-demo

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas for the github link.
the demo project is having API, web-mac, windows app (calc).
can you please point me the file which is specific to web application (not mac)
as per the documentation i was looking at the code which should look like driver.input
driver.click(locator)

also, i coudlnt find documentation for list of webelements (selenium), in selenium we have a way to capture List<WebElement> by using driver.findelements is this possible in karate?

also, what are the artifacts i can use for UI web application automation, please guide me

Comment: @LVPrasad maybe karate is too advanced for you. specific to web application: `github.feature` - ui automation is *experimental* so documentation is lacking - so again maybe you should look somewhere else. rest is up to you